# Can Drupal 7 be easily configured to inline an article on the homepage?

Tags: drupal-7

I posted, on a Drupal 7 site, an article I intended to be displayed inline (not as the title linked to another page with the article).

Is there a straightforward way to display the text of a node on the homepage, or is that an undertaking? I imagine that a theme can be edited so a block of HTML is displayed, but I really hope that isn't the best way.

What is the best approach for something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**With Node**

There are many different ways to achieve this, but the most popular way to do it is to use the views module to display the full content of the node in a block on the home page.

Then you can place that block in one of your home page regions in the block administration screen.  However this still leaves you with the full content on the home page and the actual article node.

---

**Without Node**

You would just create a simple block if you don't want the content to be a node and display that on the home page.

---

**Without Node or Block**

You could also "hard code" it directly into the `page--front.tpl.php` file if it's something you won't be updating on a regular basis.

Comment: I looked and there was no page-front.tpl.php. I copied page.tpl.php to page-front.tpl.php and, for diagnostic purposes, put a silver-backgrounded div in front of the main content. Meanwhile the homepage doesn't have a silver div, and "silver" (I used the name, not the hex code) does not appear in the homepage source... Is there any way I can register or otherwise make available the edited page-front.tpl.php?

Comment: Make sure you are using the template with two dashes  (page--front.tpl.php)